# Sort index value of list according to another list value

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort the index of one list according to the values of another list. My code is:

```
  x = ['mango','orange','butter','milk','coconut','tree','sky','moon','dog','cat','ant','pop','fog'] // sort this list
  y = ['1','10','11','12','13','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```

What I am doing is:

```
  >>> x.sort(key=lambda (a,b): y.index(a))
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
      ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

My desired result is:

```
   x = ['mango','cat','ant', 'pop', 'fog','orange','butter','milk','coconut','tree','sky','moon','dog']
```

Comment: .. is that really your desired result?

Comment: Your desired output looks wrong to me. Try: `zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda z:int(z[1])))[0]`

Comment: Yes that is my desired result, `y` represents the index number of x - 1.

Comment: then why isn't the first word of x `orange`?

Comment: just so you know, `mango` is at index 0, and `ant` is at 10, all 0-offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your cat is off.

```
>>> new = [x[int(index) - 1] for index in y]
>>> new
['mango', 'cat', 'ant', 'pop', 'fog', 'orange', 'butter', 'milk', 'coconut', 'tree', 'sky', 'moon', 'dog']
```

Comment: @user227666 Ok, I see you fixed it in your question. Please note that python lists start at index 0, that's why I am substracting 1 from the values in `y`.

Comment: I don't understand this output. Based on the second list, `"cat"` is at index 6, why is it listed second?

Comment: Oh, so `y` should not be sorted into numeric order? I misunderstood OP's intentions then.

Comment: @Cyber `'cat'` is at index `9` of `x`, so it is the tenth element of `x`. `y` is supposed to tell you that in the desired output, the tenth element of x is at position two.

Comment: In that case I will delete my answer. I answered a different question than you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the index and item together, sort and separate:

```
y = [int(index) for index in y]  # need to sort numerically, not alphabetically
x = [item for index, item in sorted(zip(y, x))]
```

This is sorted right because tuples are sorted by the first key, which is the index, and then the correct order of items is extracted as a by product of this sort.